# How to install Metatrader 4 (Windows software) under Unix/Linux based VPS

Tags: ubuntu, vps, metatrader4

I stumbled upon this [website](http://forexhoster.com/forexvps_features.html) where Metatrader 4 installed under Unix/Linux based VPS.

It can be installed through Wine.

But how to make the interface accessible through web browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install KDE / Gnome on the server, then install the VNC-server and connect to it. You can see the interface directly from the browser (with the help of online VNC clients) or install any program that supports the VNC connection and also to see the interface.